# writing to a parallel port to control electrical equipment in WIN 7

Tags: c#, windows-7

i was looking into these projects [1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4981/I-O-Ports-Uncensored-1-Controlling-LEDs-Light-Emit) and [2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7239/Control-Electrical-Appliances-using-PC) they are working in Win XP but when i register the inpout32.dll on win7 using "regsvr32 c:\inpout32.dll" i was getting an error

```
The module "c:\inpout32.dll" was loaded but the entry point DllRegisterServer was not found.
Make sure that "c:\inpout32.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again.
```

And i also came across some forums discussing about this topic of controlling Parallel port in win 7 but none had a appropriate solution to this problem

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class PortAccess
{
    [DllImport("inpout32.dll", EntryPoint="Out32")]
    public static extern void Output(int adress, int value);
}
```

and use

```
PortAccess.Output(888, 255);
```

so i would be grateful if somebody helps me out of this

Comment: You cannot register the DLL, it is not a COM server.  It is otherwise completely unclear what the real problem might be.  w